# Choosing a specific CPU type in Google Cloud Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to choose the Intel Haswell CPU type for an instance on Google Cloud Engine, however it doesnt seem like its possible? At least there doesnt seem to be any setting for it in the Cloud Console.

It seems like one should be able to select any type between Intel Xeon E5 (Sandy Bridge), Intel Xeon E5 v2 (Ivy Bridge), Intel Xeon E5 v3 (Haswell) or Intel Xeon E5 v4 (Broadwell).

Maybe its only possible through the APIs?

Answer (score 1):

The CPU type is based on the zone where you deploy your VM. For example zone Europe-west1-d is using Haswell cpu's and Europe-west1-c is using the Ivy Bridge cpu. 
More details can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is now possible to [specify a minimum cpu](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform), but it is in beta as of writing this post.